# Message duplication and memory leak on socket io in use Effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io, memory-leaks, use-effect

Hi i have an issue with socket.io in useEffect if I go back then I come back on my page and I write a message the memory will leak and the messages will be duplicated..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
//import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Message from "../../component/Message";
import { getUser } from "../../service/account";
import { getFirebaseUser, getUid } from "../../service/firebase";
const socket = io("localhost:5002", { path: "/api/chat"});

const Chat = () => {
    
    const [inputField,setInputField] = useState("");
    const [messages,setMessages] = useState([]);
    const { expertUid } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        getFirebaseUser().then(async (res) => {
            if (res) {
                socket.emit("join", {
                    from: res.uid,
                    to: expertUid
                });
                socket.on("broadcastClientMessage", data => {
                    setMessages(messages => [...messages,data]);
                });
            }
        });

        return(()=>{
            setMessages([]);
            socket.off("join")
        })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I patched with this :

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(io(null, { path: "/api/chat"}));

    useEffect(() => {
        setSocket(io(URL, { path: "/api/chat"}));
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        getFirebaseUser().then(async (res) => {
            console.log("cc")
            if (res) {
                socket.emit("join", {
                    from: res.uid,
                    to: expertUid
                });
                socket.on("broadcastClientMessage", data => {
                    setMessages(messages => [...messages,data]);
                });
            }
        });

        return(()=>{
            setMessages([]);
            socket.disconnect();
        })
    }, [socket]);
```

Comment: This is a little bit hacky, I don't know how important is it to you to be clean. You can find more information about clean approach here: https://dev.to/bravemaster619/how-to-prevent-multiple-socket-connections-and-events-in-react-531d

Why this isn't clean? Well socket shouldn't be in useState hook, useState hook is support for change detection and rerendering. And here you want to do, when you render component make a connection, when you remove it disconect. So I would recommend for start, removing useState hook, and trying to solve this with code I suggested on the top, or from this blog.

Answer (score 1):

Socket io have a socket.disconnect() method that is recommended for disconnecting.
Try replacing your return function with

```
return(()=>{
        setMessages([]);
        socket.disconnect()
    })
```

Also move your line connection inside useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    //move this line here, and remove it from top
    const socket = io("localhost:5002", { path: "/api/chat"});

    getFirebaseUser().then(async (res) => {
```

This ensures that you are connecting and disconnecting when Chat component is present and removed from the DOM.

You can also switch on and off only message channel, and not killing whole connection inside your useEffect like this:

```
      const eventHandler = () => setConnected(true);
      socket.on('WELCOME_FROM_SERVER', eventHandler);
      // unsubscribe from event for preventing memory leaks
      return () => {
         socket.off('WELCOME_FROM_SERVER', eventHandler);
      };
```

Comment: Hey @Wings thank you but If i do that it will work but if I leave the page and come back it will not work anymore :/ because because i'm not connected anymore. I tried to put `const socket = io("localhost:5002", { path: "/api/chat"}); `in useState but if I do this socket emit no longer exists

Comment: I see, you should also move your const socket = io("localhost:5002", { path: "/api/chat"}); line inside your useEffect hook, to ensure that you connect whenever Chat component is rendered. I edited answer.